# What's the difference between DDRB and DDB data direction?

Tags: microcontroller, c

I am currently programming an nRF24L01 using an ATmega328p microcontroller.

I have come across pin data direction. I have always used DDR in the past; for example, the first line below (DDRB) is familiar to me, but I do not understand DDB3, DDB4, and DDB5.

```
#define DDR_SPI     DDRB
#define DD_MOSI     DDB3
#define DD_MISO     DDB4
#define DD_SCK      DDB5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `DDRB` means the whole register, `DDB0` means Bit 0 of register `DDRB`

Answer (score 2):

DDB5 is to DDRB what PORTB5 is to PORTB; you can write `DDRB |= (1<<DDB5)` to set pin 5 of port B to output just like you can write `PORTB |= (1<<PORTB5)` to set pin 5 of port B high.

As far as I can tell, the values of `DDB5` and `PORTB5` are just `5` for every AVR chip there is, so the only reason to use them is if you think they have mnemonic value, or maybe to generate a compile error if your target doesn't have a PORTB (or doesn't have a pin 5 on that port?)

Comment: PORTB |= (1<<PORTB5) is to set pin high and DDRB |=(1<<PORTB5) to set the data direction so dont know why DDB5 have been used whats the advantage

Answer (score 1):

The mystery is revealed if we Read The Friendly Manual (Atmega328P datasheet):
[image]

Here we can see that the bit masks are officially named `DDB7` and so on from Atmel. (Arguably it would make more sense to name them `DDRB7` but they didn't do that.) Always use the same bit mask names as stated in the manual. As we can see both `DDB7` and `PORTB7` will always be 0x80.

The reason why we use bit names is to avoid magic numbers. `DDRB |= 0x80u;` is less readable, as is `DDRB |= (1u << 7);`.

`DDRB |= (1u << PORTB7);` would just be confusing.

Although in practice you probably wouldn't be using these bit mask names directly, but those `#defined` for the hardware peripheral. In production code we might write:

```
DDR_SPI = (1u << DD_MOSI) | 
          (0u << DD_MISO) | 
          (1u << DD_SCK)  ;
```

Where `(0u << DD_MISO)` is `0` and is therefore only there as self-documenting code, stating that you intend for MISO to be an input.

---

As for what "DDR" stands for, on "Motorola-flavoured" MCUs like AVR, it means Data Direction Register. Motorola always named GPIO port registers as `PORTX`/`DDRX` and AVR picked it up from there.